# Wobbling on Shimano Nexus 8

Tags: shimano, hub, nexus

My rear wheel has a Shimano nexus 8 internal gear shift.

i noticed some wobbling on the axis recently. that means there is a little bit of play when i try to twist the axis sideways respective to the wheel itself.

is there a way to fix this?

edit: there is a nut on one side of the axis. if i tighten that one, it fixes the wobble, but it also makes the whole wheel harder too move. if it turn it while in air, it stop quite quickly by itself

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to tighten the hub bearings.  I'd take it to a shop and ask for a hub bearing adjustment.

On most hubs I'd say you can do it yourself but the Nexus series are complicated and have different features depending on the model.
This means most step-by-step directions for standard hubs won't apply.  E.g. it may have a brake built into it.

You're better off paying an expert to do it IMHO.